# PHP - How to get back to previous page if previous page method was get?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm using Laravel and I want to redirect the user back to previous page when clicking on back button. What I've done is to set the href of my anchor tag to `{{url()->previous()}}`. But now the problem is that if the previous page method was POST, it can't return back so I prefer to redirect the user back 2 times. How can I get previous page method in order to set a condition that if the previous page is GET to return back else return two times back?

Comment: One solution is to never load a page from a POST request. Your controller method should handle the POST request, do whatever needs to be done, and then redirect to a GET request to show the results. That helps prevent accidental re-submitting of POSTs, and make navigation much easier.

Comment: You could may be do it this way <a href=“#” onclick=“history.go(-1)”>Go back</a>

Comment: There is also a `redirect()->back()` mechanic in Laravel but it is not an easy implementation. It takes into account a `referrer` header or an URL saved in the session. Note that The `redirect()->back()` should be called inside a controller though